# select an option based on array of terms

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

What I’m trying to do is select an option based on the url. So what I have done so far is get the url and match it to the options. Then stored the matches in an array, next I removed a few terms like ‘http’,’org’, etc.. I was able to narrow it down to two keywords.

Now what I have to is select an option that match one of the keywords in the array.

I tried to use ‘filter’, contains: and map but it only work if I’m using one term and the array, I have an array of terms. So what I need to know how to do is select and option based on the first match. From the text of the option to the term in the  array.

```
//this is my arr
var arr = ["Pro_life", "Inactive"]

//this is the text from the options
FB_Ext_Pro_life_Specific_Inactive
FB_register_now
```

i need to find a way to select 'FB_Ext_Pro_life_Specific_Inactive' with a term from my array.
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: can you include more of your code

Comment: Just filter with both options and do an "or"? (`||`) Or an "and" if you need both to be found (`&&`)

Comment: use what do you think would help? how I'm getting the select options or how I generated the terms array?

Comment: Develop a heuristic algorithm.

Comment: the terms in  array will change based on the url. So I need a way to select an option with out knowing the actually terms.

Comment: You can select array values using their position, e.g. `array[0]`for the first item, is that what you're looking for? (Your question's really not very clear)

Comment: thanks for the idea of targeting the position of the array and also using 'and' or 'or' operators. Think I got something going now. Now to see if it hold up. lol. THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: If the options always have the same pattern, and you need EXACT matches anyways, you can string split them options and then check if the option contains your array values: https://jsfiddle.net/8kzns40k/1/ Doesn't work though if the values in the arr also contain underscores...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get your question completely, but i managed to make this

```js
var arr = ["Pro_life", "Inactive"]

var options = ["FB_Ext_Pro_life_Specific_Inactive", "FB_register_now", "sample_Inactive__"]

for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < options.length; y++) {
    if (options[y].indexOf(arr[x]) != -1) {
      console.log("Option " + options[y] + " matches with " + arr[x]);
    }
  }
}
```

It uses `indexOf()` for checking if the keyword matches with the option

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do like this;

```js
var arr = ["Pro_life", "Inactive"],
    str = "FB_Ext_Pro_life_Specific_Inactive\nFB_register_now",
 result = str.split("\n")
             .filter(s => arr.some(k => s.indexOf(k) !== -1));
console.log(result);
```